# React typescript, what are the render props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im trying to setup a router whose missing routes will redirect to /error , problem is that with typescript it doesnt allow me to use render

```
const App: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={ChartContainer} exact />
      <Route path="/error" component={Error} />
      <Route path="/" render={() => history.push("")} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

> index.d.ts(92, 5): The expected type comes from property 'render'
> which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<{}, "/">> & Readonly<RouteProps<"/",
> {}> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<...>>> & Readonly<...>'

What are the types that i have to use? And how do i type render?

Comment: I really don't understand this Route `<Route path="/" render={() => history.push("")} />`. What do you want to do?

Comment: redirect to / on invalid router @GiovanniEsposito . Since i dont have a specific 404 component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Redirect`  instead `history`

```
<Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/your-path" />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The render props accepts a function that should return a JSX component (or something that React could render)